# How to make varnish not cache a certain folder

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl, simplesamlphp

I am currently trying to setup a simplesamlphp authentication for my website but during the configuration I keep running into a redirect loop when logging in as administrator. I came to the conclusion it was because a session could not be initiated which I think was being caused by the simplesaml folder being cached. I'm trying to make it so the simplesaml folder on my server is not cached. I have edited the default.vcl file on my server and have the following setup

```
  # Do not cache these paths.


if (req.url ~ "^/status\.php$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/update\.php" ||
  req.url ~ "^/install\.php" ||
  req.url ~ "^/batch/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/admin" ||
  req.url ~ "^/admin/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/user" ||
  req.url ~ "^/user/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/users/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/info/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/flag/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^.*/ajax/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^.*/ahah/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/simplesaml/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/saml_login"){
   return (pass);
  }
```

As you can see I have added the simplesaml folder to not be cached but it won't work. I'm struggling to see where I'm going wrong.

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Add header to know if you hit or miss to check what is wrong

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean add information to know if the request hits or misses, you have an example here https://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleHitMissHeader

Answer (score 0):

The VCL is correct.
It might take some time before it kicks in because it might be the simplesaml files TTL is not expired yet and you still have in cache the simplesaml files. Once the files are nuked and a new request for that folder will be triggered that content won't be cached.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's been quite a while and the redirect error still seems to be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub vcl_rec {

if (req.url ~ "^/status\.php$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/update\.php" ||
  req.url ~ "^/install\.php" ||
  req.url ~ "^/batch/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/admin" ||
  req.url ~ "^/admin/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/user" ||
  req.url ~ "^/user/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/users/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/info/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/flag/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^.*/ajax/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^.*/ahah/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/simplesaml/.*$" ||
  req.url ~ "^/saml_login"){
   return (pass);
  }



}
```

if condition should be inside vcl_rec, than all works.

#wordpress sample

```
    sub vcl_recv {

/*
    # Blocks
    if (req.http.user-agent ~ "^$" && req.http.referer ~ "^$") {
        return (synth(204, "No content"));
    }
    if (req.http.user-agent ~ "(ahrefs|bingbot|domaincrawler|dotbot|mj12bot|semrush)") {
        return (synth(204, "Bot blocked"));
    }
    # If we host multiple domains on a server, here you can list the domains you DO NOT want to cache
    # The first check matches both naked & "www" subdomains. Use the second for non generic subdomains.
    if (
        req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?(domain1.com|domain2.org|domain3.net)" ||
        req.http.host ~ "(subdomain.domain4.tld|othersubdomain.domain5.tld)"
    ) {
        return (pass);
    }
*/

    # LetsEncrypt Certbot passthrough
    if (req.url ~ "^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Forward client's IP to the backend
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.X-Real-IP) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Real-IP;
        } else if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
    }

    # httpoxy
    unset req.http.proxy;

    # Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird.
    if (
        req.request != "GET" &&
        req.request != "HEAD" &&
        req.request != "PUT" &&
        req.request != "POST" &&
        req.request != "TRACE" &&
        req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.request != "DELETE"
    ) {
        return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # === URL manipulation ===
    # First remove the Google Analytics added parameters, useless for our backend
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "");
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?&", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }

    # Strip hash, server doesn't need it.
    if (req.url ~ "\#") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\#.*$", "");
    }

    # Strip a trailing ? if it exists
    #if (req.url ~ "\?$") {
    #    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    #}

    # === Generic cookie manipulation ===
    # Remove the "has_js" cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ga=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gat=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmctr=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmcmd.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmccn.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove DoubleClick offensive cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__gads=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the AddThis cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__atuv.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp test cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove a ";" prefix in the cookie if present
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

    # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Check for the custom "X-Logged-In" header (used by K2 and other apps) to identify
    # if the visitor is a guest, then unset any cookie (including session cookies) provided
    # it's not a POST request.
    if(req.http.X-Logged-In == "False" && req.request != "POST") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    # === DO NOT CACHE ===
    # Don't cache HTTP authorization/authentication pages and pages with certain headers or cookies
    if (
        req.http.Authorization ||
        req.http.Authenticate ||
        req.http.X-Logged-In == "True" ||
        req.http.Cookie ~ "userID" ||
        req.http.Cookie ~ "joomla_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" ||
        req.http.Cookie ~ "(wordpress_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|wp-postpass|comment_author_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|woocommerce_cart_hash|woocommerce_items_in_cart|wp_woocommerce_session_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)"
    ) {
        #set req.http.Cache-Control = "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";
        #set req.http.Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
        #set req.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        return (pass);
    }

    # Exclude the following paths (e.g. backend admins, user pages or ad URLs that require tracking)
    # In Joomla specifically, you are advised to create specific entry points (URLs) for users to
    # interact with the site (either common user logins or even commenting), e.g. make a menu item
    # to point to a user login page (e.g. /login), including all related functionality such as
    # password reset, email reminder and so on.
    if(
        req.url ~ "^/addons" ||
        req.url ~ "^/administrator" ||
        req.url ~ "^/cart" ||
        req.url ~ "^/checkout" ||
        req.url ~ "^/component/banners" ||
        req.url ~ "^/component/socialconnect" ||
        req.url ~ "^/component/users" ||
        req.url ~ "^/connect" ||
        req.url ~ "^/contact" ||
        req.url ~ "^/login" ||
        req.url ~ "^/logout" ||
        req.url ~ "^/lost-password" ||
        req.url ~ "^/my-account" ||
        req.url ~ "^/register" ||
        req.url ~ "^/signin" ||
        req.url ~ "^/signup" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wc-api" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-admin" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-login.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^\?add-to-cart=" ||
        req.url ~ "^\?wc-api="
    ) {
        #set req.http.Cache-Control = "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";
        #set req.http.Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
        #set req.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        return (pass);
    }

    # Don't cache ajax requests
    if(req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest" || req.url ~ "nocache") {
        #set req.http.Cache-Control = "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store";
        #set req.http.Expires = "Mon, 01 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT";
        #set req.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        return (pass);
    }

    # === STATIC FILES ===
    # Properly handle different encoding types
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elseif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elseif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm (aka crappy browser)
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all cookies for static files & deliver directly
    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|ogg|ogm|opus|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        return (lookup);
    }

    return (lookup);

}
```

more better perfect cache configuration follow guideline with example.

https://gist.github.com/tejastank/8b9ead9129e1ef9960ccb8d39ebc5067#file-default-vcl_preface-md